# Рандомный файл

Tags: javascript

У меня есть путь к папке. В папке лежат картинки.
Как мне взять рандомную картинку и использовать ее?

Comment: считуете все файлы каталога, ложите в массив, считаете длину массива, потом пишите чтото типа <br>`$images[ rand(0, $imagesLength) ];` - PROFIT

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = new Array('pic1.jpg','pic2.jpg','pic3.png');
var rand_file_index = Math.round(Math.rand()*(images.length-1));
rand_file_name = images[rand_file_index];//Далее его можно вставить, например, в SRC
```

Comment: Хм. Это если я знаю названия.
А если я не знаю названия?

Comment: Чистым яваскриптом - никак. =) У него нет доступа к директориям на сервере в общем случае. Надо на PHP лепить что-то типа:

    $files = scandir('./img');
    foreach($files as $key=>$file){
     if($file=='..' || $file=='.'){
      unset($files[$key]);
     }
    }
    printf('var images = new Array("'.implode('"."',$files).'");');

Comment: Если не знаешь названия считай их и положи в массив, в чем проблема?

Comment: AlexWindHope, пример привести можешь?